# Processing a long request in Tornado never finishes

Tags: python, tornado

I have the following HTTP server written using Tornado:

```
def reindex(index):
    # After some initialization, we execute a process and wait for its output
    result = subprocess.check_output([indexerBinPath, arg])

class ReindexRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def post(self):
        reindexRequest = json.loads(self.request.body)
        p = self.application.settings.get('pool')
        p.apply_async(reindex, [ reindexRequest['IndexName'] ], callback = self.onIndexingFinished)         

    def onIndexingFinished(self, output):       
        self.flush()        
        self.finish()
        logger.info('Async callback: finished')

application = tornado.web.Application([ 
  (r"/reindex", ReindexRequestHandler)
], pool = Pool(8), queue = Queue())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8625)
    try:
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
```

In the `POST` handler, I asynchronously execute the `reindex` function which in turn launches a process and wait for it to finish. That works fine - the process is always executed correctly. The process may, depending on its arguments, take up to several minutes to finish. If it completes within seconds, everything works fine.

However, when it takes e.g. over 3 minutes to complete, the HTTP client which sent the `POST` request never gets the answer. From the standpoint of the server, it looks ok - I can see **Async callback: finished** logged. However, the HTTP client waits indefinitely for the response (until it fails with a timeout). I had tried both Fiddler's request composer and the .NET `HttpClient` class.

Why does the HTTP client never gets the response if the request takes long to process?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar handler and the self.finish() will trigger the response back to the client.  So if you move that line to above your p.apply_async it ought to work as you intend.